# Select values with different separation mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file with several elements. From Spark Scala I want to select just one of these values. But their form of separation is different for the different values.
The file I have is the following:

```
"test, 27.08.2020.14.56.30, mary, products=[Product{id=123, origin=in}]"
"test, 27.08.2020.14.58.50, ane, products=[Product{id=1245, origin=on}]"
```

The objective is to obtain a table of this kind

```
class             date              name       id
 test     27.08.2020.14.56.30       mary      123
 test     27.08.2020.14.58.50       ane       1245
```

I want to join the attributes on the same line, then associate that header and print a table with those values.

```
val file= sc.textFile("C:\Users\test.txt")
val name = file.map(_.split(",")).map{x => (x(0),x(1),x(2))}
val id = file.map(_.split("=")).map{x => (x(3))}
val all = name.union(id).collect
val newNames = Seq("class","date","name","id")
val df = all.toDF(newNames: _*)
df.show()
```

But, as a last element, I just want to select the "id" with the value "123" and I also don't know how to select just that number, taking into account that the separation is different. And the moment I gather the elements, it gives me error. How can I select those elements and join them to later associate with the header?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understood your question but have you tried this?

```
val tstSeq = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/user/admin/tst.txt")

val all = tstSeq.map(_.split(",")).map{x => (x(0),x(1),x(2), x(3).split("=")(2))}

val newNames = Seq("class","date","name","id")
val df = all.toDF(newNames: _*)

df.show
```

The output of this is :

```
+-----+--------------------+-----+----+
|class|                date| name|  id|
+-----+--------------------+-----+----+
| test| 27.08.2020.14.56.30| mary| 123|
| test| 27.08.2020.14.58.50|  ane|1245|
+-----+--------------------+-----+----+
```

OR:

```
val tstSeq = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/user/admin/tst.txt")

val all = tstSeq.map(_.split(",")).map{x => (x(0),x(1),x(2), x(3).split("=")(2), x(4).split("=")(1).replace("}", "").replace("]", ""))}

val newNames = Seq("class","date","name","id", "origin")
val df = all.toDF(newNames: _*)
df.show(false)
```

To get this output:

```
+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------+
|class|date                |name |id  |origin|
+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------+
|test | 27.08.2020.14.56.30| mary|123 |in    |
|test | 27.08.2020.14.58.50| ane |1245|on    |
+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------+
```

Comment: Your idea is correct and that's exactly what I want. I wanted to make the second suggestion to get the other values. If you do just replace it works, but it will get the values all in a row, and I just wanted "123". For that I put the Split, as suggested, but it gives error: `ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 37.0 (TID 2009)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 `

Comment: that is because you have rows where you don't have the exact same pattern :(, if you can send a bigger snapshot of it, I'm going to help you

Comment: I have this input `2020-08-28 05:16:10,teste,123,user.admin.novo.info.rules`. I want to get the date, name, id and just the information saying "rules" and send it to a new file. I can only select the word "rules", but alone, without the other elements and I wanted to print all four simultaneously

Comment: this is the mistake I have:
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 37.0 (TID 2009)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at $line130.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:26)
...
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 37.0 (TID 2009, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
        at $line130.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:26)...

Comment: Those are the only 2 styles of rows that are in your input? 
2020-08-28 05:16:10,teste,123,user.admin.novo.info.rules.
test, 27.08.2020.14.56.30, mary, products=[Product{id=123, origin=in}]
If yes, in this case you can do a regex pattern to work with both of those formats

Comment: At the moment, I'm only working with the first input you just indicated, with the `2020-08-28 05: 16: 10, test, 123, user.admin.novo.info.rules`. But I can only export the information `rules` or `2020-08-28 05: 16: 10, test, 123, user.admin.novo.info.rules`. I can't pass this `2020-08-28 05: 16: 10, teste, 123, rules`

Comment: Is the regex interesting for what I want? How it works?